# Is it possible to compute $\int_e^{e^2}\frac{e^xdx}{x\ln(x)}$

Tags: integration

One of my students asked to compute this integral

$$\int_e^{e^2}\frac{e^xdx}{x\ln(x)}$$
i tried the substititions $t=e^x$, $t=\ln(\ln(x))$, by parts but no answer.

Thanks in advance for an answer or a hint.

Comment: Have you tried with residue theorem?

Comment: @Joe No. it is out of program.

Comment: My attempt so far: $\int _e ^{e^2} \frac {e^xdx} {x\ln(x)} = \int _e ^{e^2} e^x \frac 1 {\ln(x)} d (\ln(x)) = \int _e ^{e^2} e^x d(\ln(\ln(x)))$ Let $t = e^x$, so $x = \ln(t)$. $\int _e ^{e^2} e^x d(\ln(\ln(x))) = \int _{e^e} ^{e^{e^2}} t d(\ln(\ln(\ln(t))))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the sustitution $x=e^y$ and you arrive to

$$\int_e^{e^2}\frac{e^xdx}{x\ln(x)}=\int_1^2\frac{e^{\,e^{\,y}}}{y}dy$$

Consider the generating functionof Bell numbers (see [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number))

$$e^{\,e^{\,y}}=e\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!}y^n$$

and your integral reads

$$\int_e^{e^2}\frac{e^xdx}{x\ln(x)}=e\left(\,\int_1^2\frac{1}{y}dy+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!}\int_1^2 y^{n-1}\right)=e\left(\,\ln 2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!}\frac{2^n-1}{n}\right)$$

Comment: Why it is not the case that $\int _e ^{e^2} \frac {e^xdx} {x\ln(x)} = \int _1 ^2 \frac {e^{e^y}dy} {ye^y}$? Where did I mess up?

Comment: Thanks a lot . appreciate.

Comment: @user12986714 the $e^y$ in denominator disappear with $e^y\,dy$ at numerator

Comment: @popi Thank you